# How to install extra-requires from a github link with `pip`

Tags: python, git, pip, setuptools

I have this python package located in a github repository. I can install it from the github link directly like so :

```
pip install git+https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs.git
```

---

I would like to do the same, but install some extra dependencies. When using just the package name, we can do :

```
pip install mkdocs[i18n]
```

But if I try :

```
pip install git+https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs.git[i18n]
```

It fails with the following error :

> Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
>
> Collecting git+https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs.git[i18n]
> Cloning [https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs.git[i18n]](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs.git%5Bi18n%5D) to /tmp/pip-req-build-1ykhyonq
> Running command git clone -q 'https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs.git[i18n]' /tmp/pip-req-build-1ykhyonq
> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs.git[i18n]/': The requested URL returned error: 400
>
> WARNING: Discarding git+https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs.git[i18n]. Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q 'https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs.git[i18n]' /tmp/pip-req-build-1ykhyonq Check the logs for full command output.
>
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q 'https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs.git[i18n]' /tmp/pip-req-build-1ykhyonq Check the logs for full command output.

---

**How can I use extra-dependencies with github links ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following example 7 from https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#examples :

```
pip install "mkdocs[i18n] @ git+https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs.git"
```

The '@' symbol usage is is explained in detail in PEP 440, in the section [direct references](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#direct-references).

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
pip install "git+https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs#egg=mkdocs[i18n]"
```

Added `#egg=mkdocs`.

Comment: This also works with `pip install --editable`, whereas the other solution does not!